# Игнорирование таблицы стилей для uncss в gulp

Tags: gulp

В таблице имеются стили динамически созданных элементов страницы. При прохождении через uncss, эти стили удаляются.

Как запретить отслеживание таблицы стилей в gulp-uncss?

```js
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 30 versions'],
      cascade: false
    })))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', uncss({
            html: ['./app/index.html'],
            ignoreSheets: ['app/css/test.css']   // не работает!!! 
        })))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

В соседнем вопросе нашел такой вариант, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос:

> В стилях укажите комментарий перед строкой, которая попадает под
>   исключение. Ниже указываю пример на CSS. Для Saas понадобится
>   комментарий, который не удаляется при компиляции.

```
/* uncss:ignore */
.selector1 {
    /* this rule will be ignored */
}
```